# Testing equivalence in strings with different character sets

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have to synchronize a number of tables with string columns between two databases:

- the source Oracle 10.2.0.3 NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252, NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE
- the destination Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 NLS_CHARACTER_SET AL32UTF8, NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE

The source database is an off the shelf product that I have limited ability to change.  It stores strings as NCLOB which are truncated with DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR and presented in a view as NVARCHAR2(2000). The destination database stores the same strings as VARCHAR2(4000).

When I execute a statement like

```
Select origin.view_description, destination.description
from origin, destination
where origin.pk = destination.pk
and origin.view_description <> destination.description
```

I get hundreds of results that are identical for case, white space and hidden characters. I verified the identical nature using two text tools.  The only difference I can find is the length of the description due to the difference in character set.

I tried using COMPOSE, CONVERT and CAST to only detect real changes in the description but this gives the same results as using only an equivalence operator.

How can I compare two strings in SQL that use different character sets and find the ones that have different text?

Edit: Raj asks if I have used CAST as in

```
where CAST(origin.view_description AS VARCHAR2(4000)) <> destination.description
```

This yields the same subset as using COMPOSE or CONVERT with AL32UTF8.  Two strings that are identical as far as upper/lower case, white space, invisible characters but have a different length.  Security restrictions mean I cannot post real data.

Comment: You don't show us real results, so just "doesn't work" probably is very subjective. Try Select cast(origin.view_description as varchar2(4000)) orig, destination.description
from origin, destination
where origin.pk = destination.pk
and cast(origin.view_description as varchar2(4000)) <> destination.description ;